# How do I cleanse the focal points?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

"Cleanse the focal points for magical energies around the College." I was given this miscellaneous objective ("Out of Balance") by Drevis Neloren in the College of Winterhold. I'm at the central well, but it doesn't seem to do anything when I activate it (and the button symbol seems to be greyed out). What do I do?

Comment: I'm considering changing the title to "Why can't I cleanse the focal points?" or "Why is [the option] greyed out?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to purify each one, you have to equip the Mystic Tuning Gloves and then go around to each focus point to activate them.

There are 3 focus points in total, they are located in:

- Hall of Countenance
- Main Courtyard
- Hall of Attainment

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Out_of_Balance

Comment: What else is there to do? Where do I get these gloves? I'd be surprised if I could complete a quest by only equipping a pair of gloves.

Comment: After you equip them you have to go around to the each of the focal points.

Comment: Massive props to @spartacus for essentially answering the question here but not posting it in his own answer.

Comment: I was wondering where did that weird glove came from

Answer (score 4):

If you approach Drevis Neloren in the Hall of Countenance at the College of Winterhold, you are able to ask him if there is any College business that you can assist with. He will then say, "There may be a matter in which your... skills... could be useful. The various points of focus for magic energies around the College have become polluted, and need cleansing. The magical energies underneath the college still require purification. Your assistance would be most useful." Choosing to agree to help, Drevis will further elaborate on what has to be done: "Very well. These specially enchanted gloves will allow you to delve directly into the focal points for these energies. Go to each focal point and remove whatever impurities you may find there. Return the gloves to me when you have finished. Please exercise caution. This is not a procedure without possible... consequences." If you ask Drevis to repeat what has to be done, he will say, "Use the gloves to clear the focal points. Return to me when you have finished. I thought I made this rather clear."